# How to Convert a Map<String, List<String>> to Map<String, String> in java 8 functional APIs

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map like bellow,

```
 [key = "car", value = ["bmw", "toyota"]]
 [key = "bike", value = ["honda", "kawasaki"]]
```

I want to convert it to another map using java 8 functional apis like bellow,

```
 [key = "bmw", value = "car"]
 [key = "toyota", value = "car"]
 [key = "honda", value = "bike"]
 [key = "kawasaki", value = "bike"]
```

Comment: Did you try inverting then without functional APIs first?

Comment: Doing it using iteration is not a problem, want to do it with functional apis

Comment: Why, though? I suspect any functional solution will be much less readable and clear (and possibly slower and more verbose) than the straightforward imperative approach.

Comment: What if there are duplicate values?

Comment: `for (String k : map.keySet()) {
            List<String> keys = map.get(k);
            for (String key : keys) {
                result.put(key, k);
            }
        }` would do precisely what you're looking for. Not sure if any suggested solution could be more readable or provide a performance benefit. Also what about the duplicate(values turned to) keys as asked by @shmosel as well?

Comment: @shmosel lets assume there will be no duplicate values. I just wanted to check how complicated it becomes with functional apis

Comment: @nullpointer: you don’t need to store the key list into a local variable: `for(String k: map.keySet()) for(String key: map.get(k)) result.put(key, k);`, but in either case, it’s doing an unnecessary lookup on the map it’s iterating over, so `for(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> e: map.entrySet()) for(String key: e.getValue()) result.put(key, e.getKey());` is preferable…

Answer (score 8):

Flatten the map values to entries then collect them:

```
Map<String, String> m2 = map
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(v, e.getKey())))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

This can be shortened by importing `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` and `Map.Entry`.

Comment: You can shorten the final line by using `Map.Entry` (or just `Entry`) instead of `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`.

Comment: @teppic in `9` there is `Map.entry` method to use instead of a `Pair` or `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`

Comment: @Eugene: but everyone should be aware that they are not identical, i.e. `Map.entry` does not allow `null`, neither for key nor for value. If that is understood and not a problem for the actual use case, it might be the preferable option.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that doesn’t need constructing temporary `Map.Entry` instances, is:

```
Map<String, String> result = source.entrySet().stream()
  .collect(HashMap::new, (m,e)->e.getValue().forEach(k->m.put(k,e.getKey())), Map::putAll);
```

You might notice the similarity to the non-stream solution

```
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
source.forEach((key, value) -> value.forEach(k -> result.put(k, key)));
```

or the pre-Java 8 solution

```
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
for(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> e: source.entrySet())
    for(String key: e.getValue()) result.put(key, e.getKey());
```